# How to implement methods and state for vue.js component

Tags: vue.js

I'm a beginner in VueJS. And as part of my learning process, I'm building a knob for my Pomodoro app. This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamanoopchandran/d4g19zo9/2/).
I copied the knob code from codepen, which is implemented using jquery. As you can see in the fiddle most of the job is done by jquery.
I need to try and do this using Vue.js, using its methods and states. 
How to refactor this code to a better Vue.JS code? Any suggestions much appreciated.

```
Vue.component('timer', {

  mounted() {
  var knob = $('.knob');
  var angle = 0;
  var minangle = 0;
  var maxangle = 270;
  var xDirection = "";
  var yDirection = "";     
  var oldX = 0;
  var oldY = 0;

  function moveKnob(direction) {      
    if(direction == 'up') {
      if((angle + 2) <= maxangle) {
        angle = angle + 2;
        setAngle();
      }
    }      
    else if(direction == 'down') {
      if((angle - 2) >= minangle) {
        angle = angle - 2;
        setAngle();
      }
    }
  }

  function setAngle() {

  // rotate knob
    knob.css({
      '-moz-transform':'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
      '-webkit-transform':'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
      '-o-transform':'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
      '-ms-transform':'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
      'transform':'rotate('+angle+'deg)'
    });

  // highlight ticks
    var activeTicks = (Math.round(angle / 10) + 1);
    $('.tick').removeClass('activetick');
    $('.tick').slice(0,activeTicks).addClass('activetick');

  // update % value in text
    var pc = Math.round((angle/270)*100);
    $('.current-value').text(pc+'%');


  }

    var RAD2DEG = 180 / Math.PI;
    knob.centerX = knob.offset().left + knob.width()/2;
    knob.centerY =  knob.offset().top + knob.height()/2;           
    var offset, dragging=false;
    knob.mousedown(function(e) {
      dragging = true;
      offset = Math.atan2(knob.centerY - e.pageY, e.pageX - knob.centerX);
    })
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
      dragging = false
    })
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
      if (dragging) {
        if (oldX < e.pageX) {
          xDirection = "right";
        } else {
          xDirection = "left";
        }   
        oldX = e.pageX;
        if(xDirection === "left") {
          moveKnob('down');
        } else {
          moveKnob('up');
        }
        return false;
      }
    })
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example runs without jQuery.

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/d6vashmu/6/

1. Declare all the variables you need in the `data` function.
2. Declare all functions under the `methods` property.
3. Declare variables that are derived from other variables in the `computed` property, such as `knobStyle`, `activeTicks`, and `currentValue`, which are all computed from `angle`. Whenever `angle` changes, these 3 computed properties will automatically update.

Regarding the general usage of Vue, you should focus on manipulating the data, and letting Vue update the DOM for you.